# Generate Crystal Report in ASP.Net Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am following several tutorials to generate crystal reports but at the end when I try to run my code I see a blank web page. I dont get any error. What is wrong? Please help me figure out. I have tried several different ways but all in vain. Why am I unable to view the report even though I have used `CrystalReportViewer`

This is my code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con;
    string connString = null;
    connString = "Data Source=.;initial catalog=InvoiceSystem;user id=sa;password=rfm";
    con = new SqlConnection(connString);
    con.Open();

    string query = null;
    query = "Select * from tblInvoice";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    con.Close();
    DataSetInv ds = new DataSetInv();
    da.Fill(ds, "tblInvoice");
    ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReportInv.rpt"));
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
}
```

Comment: What is `DataSetInv` structure? It shouldn't be `DataSet` or `DataTable` something?

Comment: its name of my DataSet

Comment: No, it is **not**. I don't see _any_ `DateSet` in your code. Little bit confused, honestly. Are you try to do just `DataSet ds = new DataSet()` instead?

Comment: I am using a dataset to transfer data from the SQL server to crystal report I have created